# float value gives random value

Tags: arrays, c, random, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>


float average(float arr[], int n)
{ 
  float sum ;
  for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    sum = sum+arr[i];
    
    printf("%p\n", arr+i);
    printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
    printf("%f\n",sum );
  }
  return sum/n;

}

int main() {
  
    float arr1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%f is the average.\n",average(arr1, 5));
  
  
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, I am learning c in school, and I encountered this weird situation.
I want to write a function that gets an array of floats of length n and outputs the average of the numbers.
and I am testing with two different text editors, one is VSC and repl.it online.
I get

```
0x7ffe72970cc0
1.000000
1.000000
0x7ffe72970cc4
2.000000
3.000000
0x7ffe72970cc8
3.000000
6.000000
0x7ffe72970ccc
4.000000
10.000000
0x7ffe72970cd0
5.000000
15.000000
3.000000 is the average.
```

with repl.it, but when I use VSC,
I get

```
0x7ffeeab1b770
1.000000
-107423728669532035777298432.000000
0x7ffeeab1b774
2.000000
-107423728669532035777298432.000000
0x7ffeeab1b778
3.000000
-107423728669532035777298432.000000
0x7ffeeab1b77c
4.000000
-107423728669532035777298432.000000
0x7ffeeab1b780
5.000000
-107423728669532035777298432.000000
-21484745272737805312720896.000000 is the average.
```

this.
is there any wrong point in my code? why is it different between these two?
I appreciate any feedback, thank you !

Comment: `sum` is uninitialized, so it has junk value, and then it is used in the subsequent calculation `sum = sum+arr[i];`

Comment: You need to initialize `sum` to `0`.

Comment: Side note you, need to cast `%p` to `(void*) p + arr`

Comment: @alex01011 It needs to be `(void*)(arr + i)`. Otherwise you're trying to add to an integer to a `void*` pointer (which is invalid, but some compilers support it as an extension, which can make some bugs difficult to find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `sum` variable to zero when you declare it, like this:

```
float sum = 0;
```

A few more things:

You do not need array size if you are initializing it with values:

```
float arr1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

is equivalent to:

```
float arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

And also, instead of passing 5 as array size, you can pass:

```
sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(float)
```

which will always be the correct size regardless of number of elements.

Comment: Using `sizeof(float)` is higher maintenance. Consider `sizeof arr1/ sizeof arr1[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

In most C compilers, an uninitialized variable's value is garbage. When you say
`int x;`, what it actually does it locate memory at some address. It does not do *any* kind of initializiation of the value of `x`, so `x` now contains some value that was there before (garbage).

It seems like repl.it is doing default initialization to 0; I don't recommend using this kind of compiler, because it prevents you from actually understanding how C works.